# Less rules following the rise of FindBugs version

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs, sonar-runner

For analysing the code of Java 1.8, we had to increase the version of:

- FindBugs from 2.4 to  3.0
- SonarQubePlugin from 2.1 to 2. 3

We have a profile 'Sonar way with Findbugs’  that it has so many rules on last version , however, with the new version ,It has less than before .

Please, can you give me your suggestions or advices for correcting this defect ?

Just for example: With last version we have 23 000 defects per month and with new version  ,we have 3000 defects in the same month.

Thanks in Advance,

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Did you backup your profile before increasing the version? If yes just simply upload it again, if not you may need to add the rules back manually

Answer (score 0):

I did it.
but when I try to create a new profile Java 'Sonar Way FindBugs' by attaching the file java-sonar-way-findbugs-36373.xml (backup of the old version) , I receive all the time this error message :
"the page you were looking for doesn't exist"
The url in the browser is : http://localhost/profiles/profiles/create

Thanks in Advance,

Best regards,